# bWAPP php files display blank pages

Tags: apache-httpd, php, parrotsec

Currently trying to setup a locally hosted bWAPP server for my own personal use on an Acer Aspire running ParrotOS. I currently have Apache set up and am able to load in the `http://localhost/` address.

The welcome page displays properly, however the problem comes up when I attempt to install bWAPP. The `INSTALL.txt` file tells me that I need to navigate to `http://localhost/install.php`. I go to that address and it brings up a page that looks like this:[image]

Following the instructions I click "here", and then it takes me to a blank webpage.

So far I've tried to continue on with opening `http://localhost/login.php`, which results in a blank screen, and I've attempted to install `php8.1`, which created a whole other issue that I have to solve now. I'm new here and don't know what info is required to help, but I'll share any info that's needed so I can get this to work.

Comment: that is because of php version

Comment: Why are you playing with this when you don't know how to start resolving what appears to be a simple issue? (hint: the FIRST place you look when stuff is not working is in your logs)